# sentry tracking mobile devices OS, DEVICE -how headers should be specified to get it working?

Tags: android, ios, django, windows-phone, sentry

I am using sentry for tracking bugs in backend for mobile app running on three different platforms: iOS, Android, WindowsPhone.

Sentry has fields like: `device`, `os`. What parameters in HTTP header should be set, so the sentry parse it and match into this fields?

I am using django at backend.

E.g iOS app sends following User-Agent: `AppName/100 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/14.0.0` how should i format it so that sentry can display `os` and `device`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sentry-Android (my library), you can set up a custom capture listener to send up whatever data you want - https://github.com/joshdholtz/sentry-android#set-a-listener-to-intercept-the-sentryeventbuilder-before-each-capture

This example below sends up the wifi status and some random tag but you can send up whatever data you want.

```
// CALL THIS BEFORE CALLING Sentry.init
// Sets a listener to intercept the SentryEventBuilder before 
// each capture to set values that could change state
Sentry.setCaptureListener(new SentryEventCaptureListener() {

    @Override
    public SentryEventBuilder beforeCapture(SentryEventBuilder builder) {

        // Needs permission - <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        // Sets extra key if wifi is connected
        try {
            builder.getExtra().put("wifi", String.valueOf(mWifi.isConnected()));
            builder.getTags().put("tag_1", "value_1");
        } catch (JSONException e) {}

        return builder;
    }

});
```

Let me know if you have any further questions on this!